# External Monitor Not Found

Tags: nvidia, dell, external-monitor

I am having a difficult time trying to get Ubuntu to recognize the external monitor connected to my laptop.

**Environment**

- [Dell 7567](http://www.dell.com/en-us/shop/dell-laptops/inspiron-15-7000-gaming/spd/inspiron-15-7567-laptop/dncwf510s)
- Nvidia GTX 1050 Ti
- [Dell P2414H Monitor](http://www.dell.com/lt/business/p/dell-p2414h/pd) via DVI-to-HDMI
- Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS 64-bit

**Graphics Drivers Tried**

- 375.66 (default recommended)
- also, *all* available via [PPA](https://launchpad.net/~graphics-drivers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa):

  [image]

**Results**

[image]

[image]

[image]

**nvidia-settings**

Running `nvidia-settings` returns:

```
** Message: PRIME: No offloading required. Abort
** Message: PRIME: is it supported? no

ERROR: nvidia-settings could not find the registry key file.
This file should have been installed along with this driver at
/usr/share/nvidia/nvidia-application-profiles-key-documentation.

The application profiles will continue to work, but values cannot be
prepopulated or validated, and will not be listed in the help text.
Please see the README for possible values and descriptions.
```

Answer (score 3):

My problem in my Dell with Nvidia GPU was that when I switched to using the Nvidia card (rather than the Intel), my external monitors were not detected. I tried many "solution" but non has worked for me except for installing lightdm as my display manager:

1. `sudo apt-get install lightdm`
2. You may switch between gdm3 (Ubuntu's 18.04 default) and lightdm by executing: `sudo apt-get install lightdm`
   After I configured lightdm I just reboot and there it is a working laptop using external monitors.

I hope it helps,
yenuka

Comment: There is no difference between point 1 and 2 since they both include installing of lightdm. When installed reconfiguring is auto prompted. If you believe that it is alredy installed you can run simply `sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm`

Comment: This seems to work for me

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question, there are two options:

1. Manually [sign the Nvidia drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760671/could-not-load-vboxdrv-after-upgrade-to-ubuntu-16-04-and-i-want-to-keep-secur/768310#768310)
2. Or, [disable secure boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/843656/is-it-safe-to-disable-secure-boot/843678#843678)