# Unable to install nvidia drivers. As soon as installing it it turns into login loop

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 18.04, login, lightdm

As soon as I install the nvidia drivers, whatever the version is, it will return back to the login loop.

Using `sudo apt install nvidia-390` from `ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa` I installed the nvidia drivers. I even added the MOK key into Secure Boot. 
My nvidia-smi in tty1 returns the drivers 396.24
However I cannot login because of the loop
I change the .Xauthority and .ICEauthority nothing happen
I modified ./bashrc and ./profile back to normal nothing happen

However, As soon as I sudo `service lightdm stop` then s`udo apt purge nvidia*` then `sudo service lightdm restart` I'm able to login in again.

I need to install cuda and tensorflow for my work. I want to do it on Ubuntu cuz Windows sucks so do you guys have any suggestions and fixes?

I'm running on Ubuntu 18.04

Oh, btw I also disable Wayland and do everything on different forum suggest and there is no success in it. I have spent too many days fixing this stuff.

Thank you

Comment: Disable Secure Boot in BIOS.

Comment: lmao what r u saying is that deleting my windows partition MOK key

Comment: It doesn't mean to delete any key.

Comment: i mean when u disable secure boot i say that i might disable boot key for the operating system because my Windows is running of UEFI. I refer from this post [link] (https://askubuntu.com/questions/843656/is-it-safe-to-disable-secure-boot)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason I'm able to fix my problem:

- after `sudo service lightdm stop` go `crtl+alt+f1` to log in tty1
- `sudo apt remove nvidia*` to remove every nvidia-driver you have
- then `sudo service lightdm restart`
- login your acc again
- run terminal and then `sudo -i`. Type in your password
- according to some post on this problem people recommend to `sudo service lightdm stop`. However, in my case, I don't do it. after i install `sudo apt install nvidia-396` or any drivers from ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa that suitable to your system
- after that don't reboot immediately.
- go to Software and Update (search it in Ubuntu) then go to Additional Drivers. Check whether your driver has changed into your designated one. If not, install it one more time from the Additional Drivers.

  - after that, go to nvidia page to install cuda 9.2. Follow their instruction (recommend using the deb network installation if you have a strong internet connection)
  - then you can  type in terminal `sudo reboot now`

You will be able to login again without the loop.