# Unable to run apt-get install

Tags: boot, apt

When I am trying to install some new software using `sudo apt-get install`  I get this following message. I am scared of pressing `ok`. I have no idea what secure boot means and don't want to go through this.

```
 Your system has UEFI Secure Boot enabled.                                                                                                                     │ 
 │                                                                                                                                                               │ 
 │ UEFI Secure Boot requires additional configuration to work with third-party drivers.                                                                          │ 
 │                                                                                                                                                               │ 
 │ The system will assist you in configuring UEFI Secure Boot. To permit the use of third-party drivers, a new Machine-Owner Key (MOK) has been generated. This  │ 
 │ key now needs to be enrolled in your system's firmware.                                                                                                       │ 
 │                                                                                                                                                               │ 
 │ To ensure that this change is being made by you as an authorized user, and not by an attacker, you must choose a password now and then confirm the change     │ 
 │ after reboot using the same password, in both the "Enroll MOK" and "Change Secure Boot state" menus that will be presented to you when this system reboots.   │ 
 │                                                                                                                                                               │ 
 │ If you proceed but do not confirm the password upon reboot, Ubuntu will still be able to boot on your system but any hardware that requires third-party       │ 
 │ drivers to work correctly may not be usable.
```

Answer (score 0):

Power off the computer and star with the BIOS. Go to security menu and Disable secure boot.
Other option, please verify the topic: ["Installing third-party drivers requires configuring Secure Boot"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1104244/installing-third-party-drivers-requires-configuring-secure-boot)

With the best regards,
João Pinto