# Ubuntu 18.04 crashes after upgrade

Tags: drivers, 18.04, nvidia, upgrade, uefi

I got a new desktop and it ran perfectly with Ubuntu 17.04 and no drivers. As soon as I upgraded to 18.04 it started crashing ~30 seconds in (monitor and mouse go dead but power is still being supplied to CPU, GPU etc).

I tried set nouveau.modeset=0 but it didn't work either.

These are some of the computer components:

- Two RTX 2080 Ti GPUs
- Asus WS X299 SAGE motherboard
- Intel i9 x7900 CPU

What should I do? I have no idea where to go from here... Any help would be immensely appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried using CTRL+ALT+F1 or F2 or F3 to switch to other terminals to verify the system is "crashed" or simply that the display is not working?

Comment: I'm supposed to press CTRL+ALT+F1 right about boot screen but before login right? It doesn't do anything for me, just goes to login as normal. I havent tried the other two. When should I press them?

Comment: Have you tried to install the proprietary video driver?

Comment: So 18.04 and 16.04 (both LTS) don't work, but 17.04 does, so I installed NVDIA drivers on it and when I asked it what my GPUs were this is what it output: "1b:00.0 VGA Compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 1e07 (rev a1)" twice

Answer (score 0):

Apologies for submitting an answer without knowing for sure if this is the solution. I odn't have enough rep to comment yet.

Try adding this to your GRUB: [`nvidia-drm.modeset=1`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/NVIDIA#DRM_kernel_mode_setting) alongside `nouveau.modeset=0`. Make sure your BIOs settings are correct, too. If you installed in legacy or UEFI, boot in to the correct mode, turn off that strange setting, I believe it is called [`Secure Boot`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/843656/is-it-safe-to-disable-secure-boot) in BIOs if you have it.

Did you follow proper procedure preceding a distribution upgrade? Prior to upgrade, safe procedure dictates the removal of graphics drivers and their repositories, then adding them again after the system upgrade reboot. If you didn't, what you might be able to do is enter terminal via recovery mode and try `sudo apt remove nvidia* --purge`. Ubuntu should run fine with built in drivers. I would also definitely remove one card and boot up, then install drivers for both (if that's how it works, I'm not well-versed). As I understand dual card setups have a slew of issues, and running a unix based system instead of Windows sounds like a tough situation.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. Unfortunately it didn't work. I even tried to download the server on its own and it crashes right after I chose my time zone (no GUI yet). Should I just get the windows system? I'm trying to use this machine for machine learning.

Comment: Regarding choosing an OS to learn, Ubuntu can be considered the better option because of more compatibility with packages and system logic is the same as the programs you will use (and with that comes 'muscle memory' in running commands). Have you tried 16.04 LTS? It should be more stable and have more support with programs you may use.

Comment: 16.04 LTS and 18.04 Server installs both crash too.