# Laptop starts overheating if secure boot is enabled

Tags: boot, security, overheating

After spending hours to fix the overheating problem on my laptop running Ubuntu 20.04, I've figured it out is that all I have to do is to disable Secure Boot, the temp went down tremendously from 90~100+ oC to

```
coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Package id 0:  +56.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 0:        +54.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 1:        +56.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 2:        +52.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 3:        +52.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
```

However, I still want to enable Secure Boot while keeping my laptop from overheating, as disabling it could leave my laptop vulnerable to malware. Could you guys please give me some diagnoses and advice for this problem?

Comment: What version of Ubuntu and is it up to date?

Comment: @David 20.04, and yes it's up to date

Comment: Please edit the question and include this info.

Comment: @David I have edited the question

Comment: You may have special drivers for your fan hardware. These drivers in Ubuntu are normally unsigned. If secure boot is enabled, and the drivers are not signed, these drivers will not load, hence the overheating. In order for them to load, each driver must be "signed". This process of signing the drivers is not extremely difficult, but it can be a hassle... especially if you change/update the driver, or change/update the kernel software that is a part of Ubuntu. Old but good info here https://askubuntu.com/questions/843656/is-it-safe-to-disable-secure-boot

Comment: @darth_epoxy thanks for the info!