# what is the risk of disabling secure boot

Tags: secure-boot

I have ubuntu 22.04

I installed virtualbox so I could run a windows 10 system. I created a win10 system.
When I tried to start the win10 system there was an error. According to my research I could fix the problem by disabling secure boot. What would be the risk if any of disabling secure boot ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it safe to disable Secure Boot?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/843656/is-it-safe-to-disable-secure-boot)

Comment: See this link: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/271450/what-does-secure-boot-protect-against

Answer (score 0):

as [people](https://superuser.com/questions/1689067/can-disabling-secure-boot-affect-windows) [have](https://askubuntu.com/questions/843656/is-it-safe-to-disable-secure-boot) [said](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/271450/what-does-secure-boot-protect-against) it depends on your security requirements

if for some reason you still need it, you will need to install sbctl

```
git clone https://github.com/foxboron/sbctl.git

cd sbctl

make

sbctl
```

then follow the [upstream instructions](https://superuser.com/questions/1689067/can-disabling-secure-boot-affect-windows) to enable it, then re enable it in your bios.